# naming convention for permissions in Spring Security?

Tags: permissions, spring-security, naming-conventions

I am currently implementing a security layer in our web application using Spring Security and more precisely hasPermission() method by implementing our own PermissionEvaluator.

I am wondering if there are any naming conventions / libraries to represent permissions on model objects, action etc.

The method signature is hasPermission(Object param, Object permission) which leaves things pretty open. most people seem to be using a string as the second argument, and an object or array of object for the first argument so they end up having something like hasPermission(#object, 'edit').

- is there a standard list of permission or a convention? (view, edit, modify, create, add, delete, remove, print, list...)
- is it better to use strings, numbers, or enums for the permission?
- is there a convention to name actions (addPersonToProject, personToProjectAdd...)
- could you share some information on the implementation you are using for such roles and permissions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. It might help if you could provide a description of what your web application does and what your requirements are. For example, why would a standard list of permissions (assuming such a thing existed) be relevant to your app? What are you trying to apply permissions to?